# Add Scrolling in the ListView.builder in Flutter application

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a List view scroll able, when I googled and could not found an understandable and simple solution, I tried to make a custom scroll (example from link https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), at the moment it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
CustomScrollView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      sliver: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Items").snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return new ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,

                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return new Row(

                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Text(ds["item1"])),
                          Expanded(child: Text(ds["item2"])),
                          Expanded(child: Text(ds["price"].toString())),
                        ],
                      );
                    });
              }
              else {
                return Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );

              }
            },
          )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Below is the screenshot from emulator (Kindly node, same on the phone):
[image]

Kindly help me with pointers or sample code for scroll-able list view.

Comment: are you simply trying to make a list that you can scroll right ?

Comment: Yes, I have to use ListView builder constructor too

Comment: if you want simple scrollable list just use `ListView.builder` - you dont need anything else, see [here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists#complete-example) for example

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a CustomScrollView. ListView is a scrolling widget itself. So you only need to create it inside your StreamBuilder.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
    stream: posts,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      }
       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return const Text('Loading...');
        default:
          if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
            return const NoContent();
          }
          return _itemList(snapshot.data);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

CustomScrollView is used for adding Sliver widget inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping a `ListView` inside a `SliverList`, which is never a good idea if they have the same scrolling direction. You could either do a `Column` with a `List.generate()` generator (inefficient) or get rid of one of the `ListView`'s:

```
CustomScrollView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Items").snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            sliver: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return new Row(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(child: Text(ds["item1"])),
                      Expanded(child: Text(ds["item2"])),
                      Expanded(child: Text(ds["price"].toString())),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                childCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

If this code snippet doesn't work swap the `StreamBuilder` with the `CustomScrollView`

Comment: what do you mean by StreamBuilder with the CustomScrollView

Comment: Put the customscrollview within the streambuilder's build function. But only do that if it doesn't work this way!

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` itself is a scroll able list so you just create it with your custom tiles. Here is the code from my to-do list app that I used to create a list of my to-do items.
Well I call this function when I have to create a list.

```
/*Called each time the widget is built.
* This function creates the list with all items in '_todoList'
* */
Widget _buildTodoList() {
  return new ListView.builder(
    // itemBuilder will be automatically be called as many times as it takes for the
    // list to fill up its available space, which is most likely more than the
    // number of to do items we have. So, we need to check the index is OK.
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < _todoList.length) {
        return _buildTodoItem(_todoList[index],index);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Now this function calls a `_buildTodoItem` function which creates a single custom list tile.

```
 /*Build a single List Tile*/
Widget _buildTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem,int index) {
  //return a custom build single tile for your list
}
```