# Get Firebase collection to a Flutter List to display

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I struggling to get data form a Firebase collection into a Sliverlist.
Every example I found like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133543/add-scrolling-in-the-listview-builder-in-flutter-application), returns only one Sliverlist, but I've multiple.

The goal I want to achive is a list of Sliverlists, where some have dynamic data en other doesn't

This is the part of my code where its happens:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            // omitted
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: false,
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
              // omitted
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("books").snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              return SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    return Row(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: Text(ds["title"])),
                        Expanded(child: Text(ds["author"])),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                StaticWidget(),
                StaticWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0)),
        ],
      ),
      // omitted
```

I getting the following error:
[image]

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Hello!,I'm having same problem,Can anybody help?